# Unable to enforce trailing slash through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, trailing-slash

I have the following content in my .htaccess file **place in the root directory**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The thing is, the '.html' does get removed from the URL, but the trailing slash is nowhere to be seen. Why? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your 301 RedirectRules before internal rewriteRules  and make the trailing slash optional in your Rule's pattern.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```